# Restrictions on Existential Introduction in first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to understand the restrictions on Existential Introduction (EI) as defined by the [Stanford introduction to logic](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/section.php?section=section_08_03). Three separate restrictions are mentioned:

- The term being replaced cannot "contain any explicitly quantified variables" (slide 8)
- The term being replaced  cannot "contain any universally quantified variables" (slides 8 and 10)
- "It is important to avoid variables that appear in the sentence being quantified" (slide 9)

These restrictions seem contradictory and confusing. Can anyone clarify exactly what is and isn't allowed in EI? Thanks.

EDIT: I understand the individual examples of invalid EI given in the linked article. What I need is to codify the general restrictions formally. In other words, I need a mechanical rule that says when EI can (or cannot) be applied.

Comment: Do you need to just formalize some logic or does it have to be exactly this?

Comment: I'd like to formalize EI in particular.

Comment: What I was trying to ask was, is it a requirement of your question to formalize this exact logic, the one presented in your slides, or did you just choose it arbitrarily?

Comment: The requirement is to formalize the rules for EI in first-order logic. If you want to use terminology or concepts that are different from Stanford's, that's fine, as long I can map them conceptually to my existing understanding of FOL (which I mainly have by reading Stanford's intro course).

Comment: Ok if you are following a course then my comment is irrelevant, I was going to suggest that it is much easier to formalize FOL when it doesn't introduce the concept of "constants" into the logic.  Both answers to this question are good I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There need be no restrictions on the rule they gave depending on how we interpret the notation $\varphi[\tau]$. I couldn't find where they define this notation. It just appears without explanation in Section 6.11 slide 4.

I'll use a slightly different notation, $\varphi[\tau/x]$, which will stand for the [*capture-avoiding* substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Capture-avoiding_substitutions)<sup>1</sup> of the term $t$ for the variable $x$ in the formula $\varphi$. Capture-avoiding substitution does substitution in a way that respects bound variables. It is a meta-logical operation on formulas and not part of the syntax of formulas themselves. It is also a partial operation that is undefined when we try to substitute a term into a formula that binds free variables in that term. That is, $(\exists x.\varphi)[f(x)/z]$ is undefined because the $\exists x$ binds a free variable in $f(x)$. We say the binder "captures" the $x$ in $f(x)$, hence "capture-avoiding". The rule can be written more formally as $(\exists x.\varphi)[t/z]$ is defined when $z=x$ or $x\notin\mathrm{FV}(t)$ where $\mathrm{FV}(t)$ stands for the set of free variables of the term $t$. In the $z=x$ case, $(\exists x.\varphi)[t/x] = \exists x.\varphi$, otherwise $(\exists x.\varphi)[t/z] = \exists x.\varphi[t/z]$ (assuming the constraint is satisfied). We have the same rules for $\forall$.

Writing the Existential Introduction using this notation gives: $$\dfrac{\varphi[t/x]}{\exists x.\varphi}$$ No side-conditions are required other than $\varphi[t/x]$ has to be defined. This roughly corresponds to their constraint that $t$ doesn't contain any variables bound in $\varphi$. It's actually a little more forgiving since $(\forall x.\forall y.\psi)[f(y)/x]=\forall x.\forall y.\psi$ even though $y$ is bound in $\forall y.\psi$.

Let's see how the examples given play out. They give two examples as warning: $$\exists  x.\mathrm{hates}(\mathrm{jill},x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\forall y.\mathrm{hates}(y,f(y))$$

Starting with the second, we'd have something like $(\forall y.\mathrm{hates}(y,x))[f(y)/x]$, but $y$ gets captured so this is undefined.

For the first formula, we have the premise $(\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(x,x))[\mathrm{jill}/x]=\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(x,x)$ and so the rule works and we validly derive $\exists x.\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(x,x)$ from $\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(x,x)$. Alternatively, we have $(\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(\mathrm{jill},x))[\mathrm{jill}/x]=\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(\mathrm{jill},x)$ which validly infers $\exists x.\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(\mathrm{jill},x)$ from $\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(\mathrm{jill},x)$. If we actually want to do something non-trivial, we'd need to do $(\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(z,x))[\mathrm{jill}/z]=\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(\mathrm{jill},x)$ which allows the valid inference of $\exists z.\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(z,x)$ from $\exists x.\mathrm{hates}(\mathrm{jill},x)$.

There are more principled ways to address this issue, such as using [nominal techniques](https://doi.org/10.2178/bsl%2F1305810911), but they require introducing a lot of machinery which is usually not worth it unless you are proving many meta-theorems about many languages with rich binding structure (as often happens in programming language theory). You can also just eliminate the problem via [de Bruijn indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index), but these aren't at all human-friendly and substitution is still not completely trivial.

The side-conditions on Existential *Elimination* are actually more sophisticated and not just a matter of performing substitution correctly. They can be made clean and clear using a different organization of the rules, but I won't go into that here.

<sup>1</sup> This link is for capture-avoiding substitution in the lambda calculus, but it is easy to adapt to first-order logic with the quantifiers taking the place of $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I need. I'm working through the details you provided and will let you know if I have any follow-up questions.

Comment: I'm having some trouble turning this into a mechanical way to determine if an arbitrary proposed EI is allowed. For example, we have premise `∃x.hates(jill, x)` and want to determine if we can derive `∃x.∃x.hates(x,x)` by replacing term `jill` with variable `x`. In this scenario, `φ = ∃x.hates(x,x)` and `φ[jill/x]` is defined but is not equal to the premise. This means that the proposed EI is invalid?

Comment: Your conclusion is right, the proposed EI is invalid, but your description of why is a bit off. We're not replacing `jill` with `x`. We have a conclusion of the form $\exists x.\varphi$. We are then performing a capture-avoiding substitution of $t$ for the free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$, i.e. $\varphi[t/x]$, and checking whether that matches the premise. A use of EI should specify the term being abstracted, e.g. like $\text{EI}_t$. We don't want to talk about replacing a term with a variable, because then we have issues when we want to abstract only some of the occurrences of a term.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me not only solve this specific problem, but also connected it to my previous understanding of lambda calculus. At this point, I'm tempted to revisit the entire project using type theory rather than first-order logic. (I assume they are basically isomorphic due to Curry-Howard.)

Answer (score 2):

In $$\forall n\colon (n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1 $$
we cannot take $\tau = n+1$ and "conclude"
$$\exists v\colon \forall n\colon v^2=n^2+2n+1.$$
But from 
 $$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1, $$
we are allowed to go to
$$\exists v\colon  v^2=n^2+2n+1.$$

Actually, explanatory examples illuminating what goes wrong are given on slides 9 and 10.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the explanatory examples. What I need help with is codifying the general restrictions formally.